# How to move to a patch that is at least x distance from a turtle

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to ask a turtle to move to any patch that is at least a distance of x away from another turtle. So in a mix of NetLogo and English it would be:

```
move-to one-of patches with [distance to nearest turtle > 4]
```

How can this be done please?

Comment: What do you want to do if there is no such patch?

Comment: I always struggle with SO around this - I want to make my question as specific as possible to me, by generic enough to be useful. In truth, I think I can handle this bit - the whole thing's going to be part of a series of if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the nearest turtle using the `min-one-of` + `[distance myself]` reporter. You also need to make sure that you only look at `other turtles` since a turtle will always be the turtle that is closest to itself.

The code can be broken up like this:

```
let nearest-turtle min-one-of other turtles [distance myself]
move-to one-of patches with [distance nearest-turtle > 4]
```

For (arguably) better readability.

edit: thanks Nicolas for the correction. You are totally right.

Comment: Not just readability: if you stick `other` in the `with` block, it refers to the calling patch. Everyone gets bitten by that. It can lead to very subtle bugs...

Comment: I think your use of `myself` in the long expression is also wrong: it refers to the calling patch, not the calling turtle like you intended.

Comment: This is where the problem started! It's the patch that should be a minimum distance from another turtle, not the turtle that is doing the moving. The use of "patch with" I think makes it so that the correct agent is doing the calling. I'll try it out tomorrow. Thanks for all comments and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Using all of the above, here is a solution:

```
to go
  ask patches [set nearest-turtle min-one-of turtles [distance myself]
    set distance-turtle distance nearest-turtle
    ]

  crt 1 [
    set color blue
    move-to one-of patches with [distance-turtle > 4]]

end
```